# exporting bootstrap table content as excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a bootstrap table with some content as shown. I wrote a code to export the table as excel. However the excel contains the `html` part of the table including the content. I want only content to be present in excel. How can I rewrite my code to do that?

```js
$('#export').click(function() {
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#table').html());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="table">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Event name</b></td>
        <td>Event 1</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Registrar name</b></td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>From</b></td>
        <td>08/18/2016 9:00 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>To</b></td>
        <td>08/19/2016 12:00 AM</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Amount collected</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cash</td>
        <td>USD 2,200.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Credit</td>
        <td>USD 4,050.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>AR</td>
        <td>USD 4,400.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FOC</td>
        <td>USD 0.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transfer</td>
        <td>USD 0.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
        <td>USD 10,650.00</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Ticket issued</b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cash - 550 USD</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>USD 2,200.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Credit card - 450 USD</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>USD 4,050.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>AR - 550 USD</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>USD 4,400.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>FOC</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>USD 0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Transfer</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>USD 0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
        <td><b>0</b></td>
        <td><b>USD 10,650.00</b></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="export" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ok26s32c/

Comment: For example you can use datatables: https://datatables.net/
In datables have good scripts with export contains html table to excel: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to do it without datatables

Comment: I did it, I used https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/

Comment: Try change $('#table').html() on $('#table').text()

Comment: Changed as suggested, only content is being posted into excel now, but all content comes in a single cell, I want to be organized just like html table.